# Why are Stack Overflow usercard links not functioning the same as other sites?

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, user-card

This might be a bug but my guess is something else is going on. My Arqade user card shows all five links that I have setup. Unfortunately my Stack Overflow user card only shows three of the links.

Here are some screen shots to illustrate:

**Arqade user card**
[image: Arqade user card with links]

**Stack Overflow user card**
[image: Stack Overflow user card without links]

The content of the two About Me sections differ. My bio on Stack Overflow is significantly longer and makes use of the `<!-- summary: -->` flag. The link code is identical on the two sites:

```
[Twitter][1] [Facebook][2] [Google+][3] [CV][4] [Blog][5]


  [1]: http://twitter.com/ahsteele
  [2]: https://www.facebook.com/ahsteele
  [3]: https://plus.google.com/117377867595475228062/
  [4]: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ahsteele
  [5]: http://www.steelebit.com
```

Why are the links of my cv and blog appearing on Arqade, but not on Stack Overflow?

**Edit**: I changed the tag on this question from [support](/questions/tagged/support) to [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). After playing with my profile the length of text entered definitely affects the links that appear on the user card. In fact using just using the `<!-- summary: -->` flag will cause the links to break. I am sure the code to parse all of this is relatively gnarly, but it is broken in its current form.

Comment: If the code is "identical", why are links 2 and 3 reversed between the two cards?

Comment: Could be a timing issue. Click "Save and Apply across all SE sites", logout and wait a bit, then check again?

Comment: @JP I don't want the same bio on all SE sites.

Comment: Maybe then it is being parsed differently because of the varying amount of bio text vs. links. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: @Toomai that's a great question. I double checked and yes they are identical in my bio, but are appearing in a different order which probably has something to do with the issue.

Comment: @JP no worries man, but I appreciate the suggestion!

Comment: There was a time adding "summary" caused the whole card to be blank, looks like they fixed it to some extent, but not fully just yet. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd There have been issues with user cards since their inception. I just got annoyed enough tonight to poke at it. :)

Comment: Only [13 bug reports](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-card+bug) so far, guess people are too lazy to report those issues! ;)

Comment: @AllDaniSpringer it's not a dupe. This is a bug report whereas the other is a support request. Further this question is much older with more up votes.

Comment: @AllDaniSpringer nothing you really can do. I don't think deleting the dupe comment will undo the dupe review. If the question gets closed as a dupe I will just need some help to get it reopened.